# How to change (my business) Google Plus images in Google Search?

Tags: google-search, google-plus

I have a Google Plus page for my business. When I type my business name in the Google search box, I can see on the right side a pane with my business details, location, images etc.

I can easily edit the information appears there, but I don't know how I can change the image appears next to GoogleMaps box (see image).

[image: google search for my business]

Is that an image which is picked by Google algorithms? Is that related to SEO only? any chance I can control this image and replace it for my business?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they take the image from either your google my business (previously called google places) or your companies google plus page. With google my business being the first choice.

I do some work for a interior design and architecture company and although the google my business page has 20-30 images on the profile the "main pic" shown in search results always seems to be set by google and rarely changes. One thing i have noticed though is that google will tend to favour using images which its algorithms believe are of an external of a building (i guess they believe this is an image of the external of your office (which if you are an architecture / building etc company it wont necessarily be true as it could be of a project you recently completed.)